# Does Revirtualization works with Hyper-V and not Xen

Tags: virtualization, virtual-machine, virtualbox, hyper-v, xen

I was installing vagrant with virtualbox provision. When I am running it on Amazon EC2, then it doesn't work saying:

```
 * Running VirtualBox in a Xen environment is not supported
```

EC2 uses xen virtualization. On the other hand, its working fine on Windows Azure Virtual Machines which uses a customized version of Hyper-V.

So,cant we use virtualbox in Xen but in Hyper-V?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that HyperV allow you to start the VM, I don't think this is possible using current hardware VT technology without slow painful emulation instead of virtualization.